# Light Gas for Large Flyers

Tags: science-based, creature-design, dragons, flight, low-fantasy

I'm kind of on a journey in search of how to scientifically explain fantastic creatures in a way that doesn't rely on magic, because I think that makes things more interesting. Currently my biggest challenge is with the flyers, especially the 6 members. Most of the answers are saying that it is impossible, others even say that it is possible, but it would not be possible for a human to assemble and it would be necessary to change the atmosphere and gravity of the planet where they live. Thinking about it I remembered that I saw a post about dragon breath right here on the WBSE, one of the answers was about the dragon expelling a gas that would ignite when coming in contact with the air, this gas would be light and help the dragon to fly better, but after the breath was used, the dragon would become heavy and could not fly until it refueled.

Based on this, the question came to me: **is it possible for an animal to produce a light gas that helps it to fly when flapping its wings and in which part of the body would this gas stay? Is it possible to produce this gas by eating meat(dragons, griffins) and plants(pégasi)?** In the case of dragons, the gas would not be used to attack as part of the breath, I already have an idea of ​​something else for the breath

A gas that the animal can produce from feeding or perhaps even breathing. Ah, the animal must be able to carry someone, a rider. My world is similar to Earth(not venus) but with an atmospheric density twice as high as, according to my research, nitrogen makes flight easier and oxygen allows for the existence of larger flying animals. In my world these animals (pégasi, dragons, griffins...) are created, they didn't arise from evolution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/57998/30492

Comment: I can't say why the question is about Venus, not about the Earth itself...

Comment: "Flame breath"? The gas doesn't need to be used to generate fire, just to help with the flight.

Comment: Attaching a gas bag to an animal (or integrating one into it's body) would vastly increase it's wind resistance and friction - the phrase "help it fly" may well be out of the question no matter what answer you get.

Comment: Short answer, Methane. A lot of animals produce it. Cows in particular produce a lot. Bacteria produces it. It's lighter than air and very flammable, but it's generated biologically more so than any other gas I know of that fits the bill.  I dont know of any animals that produce hydrogen.

Comment: Redbud201, how can a carnivore get methane through food?

Comment: @WizardKing Carnivores expel gas as well you know. They still have the bacteria in their gut.

Comment: @WizardKing Here's a non-Venusian question with roughly the same theme: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34892/evolution-of-giant-floating-mammals

Comment: KeizerHarm, this question does answer my question, not the one that was the reason my post was closed.

Comment: Although my animals won't actually float and just use it as a flight aid, thank you, it did help me.